# Multiple Types in One Variable Java

Tags: java, class, generics

In my Java program, the user can select multiple objects on the screen. When one is selected, I want to update a variable with the object that was just selected. However, these objects are instances of different classes, so how can I do this?

Comment: How about use the Object class? Or better yet, create your own super class that all these objects can logically extend.

Comment: @PCLuddite Interface would be better than superclass (and Object).

Comment: @Andreas True, that may be a better option depending on the actual layout of his code, but as the op has supplied none, I think you'd be hard pressed to find noticeable difference between the two implementations, and it boils down to a matter of opinion.

Comment: I know this is a stupid restriction and might make it not possible, but this is for a university assignment and we cannot use inheritance.

Comment: @jezza Do you consider interfaces "inheritance"?

Comment: @jezza I have no desire to use java without inheritance. That's its main selling point. However, if you have to, use the `Object` class. All classes inherit `Object` implicitly, so you won't be "using" inheritance yourself.

Comment: No I don't, but I can easily add a method to the class which can determine whether of not it is selected, which is probably more simple than using interfaces.

Comment: @jezza I'd argue using interfaces is "more  simple" simply because it makes your code easier to read and requires less code writing if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks guys, i'm using the object class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use an "Object" instance, because every classes somehow inherit Object class. When you use it, you can use typecasting to get back the original instance.

Answer (score 4):

Create an interface representing something common to all the objects, with method signatures for what you want to access on the objects.

Then create individual objects implementing that interface.

If you ever need to access the subclasses of the original objects you can use the `instanceof` operator to check whether an object is of a particular subclass and then typecast it appropriately.

Comment: The purpose of using an interface is so there would be no need for `instanceof`.

Comment: True for use of most of the methods, but there may be a need to distinguish them.  In the OP's use case, he'll be doing updateVariable(InterfaceClass) but if later he wants to know which class that variable is, he would be able to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the wildcard operator like so

```java
Set<?> example;
```

This is a bit dangerous because you lose the type safety but is a possible way if you do not mind checking for types